# Newly installed CentOS 7 boots to command line and unable to enter GUI

Tags: centos, gui

I installed `CentOS 7` from a bootable USB but when I rebooted, it went into the command line mode. I was able to log in using root but unable to get into the GUI following [these directions](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-start-gui-in-centos-7-linux/).

How do I change the config to go into the GUI automatically on login and avoid being asked to make choices by the BIOS (which also happens)?

The install process didn't even ask me for WiFi credentials. So when I go into `yum` on command line, it cannot connect to repositories. So far, very disappointed with how they packaged the install process.

Comment: During the install process, which option did you select? The default is `Minimal Installation` which doesn't include a GUI. You need to select `Server With GUI` in order to have a GUI. You can install one via `yum` but to get an internet connection, you will either need to connect via ethernet or set it via the command line.

Comment: it never asked me

Comment: actually, restarted the install and found where to pick the installation type

Comment: Sounds good. That should take care of it.

Comment: why don't you make it an answer and I'll upvote and accept it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During installation, the default is `Minimal` which doesn't have a GUI. You need to select `Server With GUI` from the installation main menu in order for a GUI to be present.